# sitte.ru/index.php/razdel - в Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, url, чпу

Подскажите как корректно убрать index.php из URL страниц сайта на Joomla 2.5, для главной страницы уже убрал дубль.

Осталась эта приставка в промежутке домена для всех остальных страниц, например: site.com/**index.php**/razdel/tovar, необходимо чтобы страницы были доступны просто по, пример: site.com/razdel/tovar

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы из URLа сайта  (пример: http://mysite.ua/index.php/uslugi) убрать через админ панель index.php необходимо,

1. В админке сайта перейти через меню по пути сайт/общие настройки/настройки seo и включить  перенаправление URL (в положение "да");
2. в корне сайта находим файл .htaccess (если он назван у вас htaccess.txt - переименовываем его в .htaccess именно с таким расширением), в нем должна быть строчка Options +FollowSymLinks, комментируем ее путем проставления перед ней "#"

## Options +FollowSymLinks[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И получаем чистые красивые URL